# Does using "there" a second time matter?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, meaning-in-context, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

I'm going to the hospital tomorrow. Usually, there are more people waiting to see the doctor than you can count, so I'll be late.

I'm going to the hospital tomorrow. Usually, there are more people waiting to see the doctor **there** than you can count, so I'll be late.

In the first example, is the sentence without the second **there** grammatically correct? Is it necessary to use the second **there**? What difference does using the second **there** make in terms of the sentence's overall meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is still grammatically correct with or without "there". "there" just points out that the doctor is in the hospital, so it makes it more specific to where the doctor is, nothing else.